# Writing a book class for LaTeX2e, \NeedsTexFormat{LaTeX2e} "not defined" error?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I have a `book` class titled `epbook.cls` with the following opening lines

```
\NeedsTexFormat{LaTeX2e}%
\ProvidesClass{epbook}[2015/11/21 The EmptyPotato Press Book Class]%
\LoadClass{book}%
\RequirePackage{titlesec}%

[redefinition of \section, \subsection, and \sub-subsection]
```

and a `test-epbook.tex` with

```
\documentclass{epbook}%

\begin{document}%
\part{The Standards}%
\chapter{K. Kindergarten}
\domain{CC. Counting and Cardinality}
\cluster{[A.]}
\paragraph{[text of cluster A]}
\standard{K.CC.A.1}
\paragraph{[text of standard 1]}
[etc.]

\end{document}%
```

At this point, I am only attempting to modify the section, subsection, and sub-subsection headers. Section is replaced with Domain, subsection with Cluster, and sub-subsection with Standard. When I compile the `.tex` file (using TeXnicCenter; LaTeX -> PDF) I get an error message saying that;

```
\NeedsTexFormat{LaTeX2e}% is an undefined control sequence.
```

Does anyone see an error in this class file?

Comment: Since this is a typo, i think this question should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a wrongly typed command

Answer (score 7):

You need to use

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
```

Note that it's spelt TeX, not Tex. Also, the optional argument at the end is, well, optional.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm with that correction.